# Unsupported This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following project with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.4

Tags: .net

Unsupported This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.

Answer (score 0):

For this we need to try the following steps
1.Open Visual Studio Installer
2.Click Modify
3.Go individual components tab
4.Then check all checkboxes inside Code Tools